# _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>') its my error

Tags: flutter

My api function:

```
 Future<List<User>>fetchData() async {
var response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(link),
    headers: headers);
 var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

List<User> users = [];

for (var u in jsonData) {
  User user = User(u["name"], u["code"], u["id"]);
  users.add(user);
}
print(users.length);
return users;
```

}

im getting this error in for loop. how can i fix it ? i need help. thanks for all

Comment: can you also share the response body?

Comment: its like ``` [
    {
      key1: value1,
      key2: value2,
      key3: value3,
    },
    {
      key1: value1,
      key2: value2,
      key3: value3,
    },
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is probably inside a list inside this json response. Look if you have a `"data"` field in your response, then your `for loop` would look something like this:

```
var u in jsonData["data"]
```

print our your `jsonData` and let's see.

Comment: yeah i print jsonData and saw my datas in terminal

Comment: should i add my data's fields like yous (["data") ?

Comment: If your json response has a field called data, and inside it your list, then yes. If you post the printed response, it would also be easier to help you.

Comment: i did it and works. we fixed this error. now faceing on more ty so much

Comment: Post your new error in another question, and we'll try to fix it :)

Comment: Awesome! Happy coding :)